# How do I keep the previous value sent to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, input

I would like to store the value of a input to JSON (on submit). If the User fill out the input again then submit I would like to add the new value to JSON keeping the previous one.

I use the following to add the input value to JSON but I'm not sure how to keep the previous value sent to JSON.

http://jsfiddle.net/ABE4T/

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="element" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" />
</form>
    <div id="display"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var arrayData = this.serializeArray();
    var objectData = {};

    $.each(arrayData, function(){
        if(objectData[this.name] != null){
            if(!objectData[this.name].push){
                objectData[this.name] = [objectData[this.name]];
            }

            objectData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        }
        else{
            objectData[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return objectData;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        $('#display').text(JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeObject()));    
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Submit the form via ajax or use a cookie to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use .append() function instead of .text() function.

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABE4T/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an array to hold all the values like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var values = [];

    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        values.push($("#myForm").serializeObject());
        $('#display').text(JSON.stringify(values));    
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/ABE4T/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value in `#display`.

Change this line

```
 $('#display').text(JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeObject()));
```

to

```
$('#display').text($('#display').text() + JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeObject()));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNQWb/)